# ¿Cómo crear una gráfica de líneas en la que se superpongan dos data frames?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, dataframe

Deseo generar una gráfica en la que se muestren dos líneas, una de cada data frame, de manera que pueda constatar visualmente en una misma gráfica la diferencia entre los datos de cada df.

Estoy trabajando con `ggplot`, de manera que tengo 2 gráficas (una para cada data frame) pero que, por comodidad a la hora de visualizar, me gustaría tener una sola gráfica donde se observen ambas líneas.

¿Hay forma de hacer esto?

Inserto el código que tengo para cada gráfica por separado (que realmente sólo cambia el data frame de entrada)

**Gráfica 1**

```
(ggplot(estacionesNuevas[[4]], aes(x = event_time, y = event_value)) +
    ggtitle("Gráfico1") +
    xlab("Hora") +
    ylab("Temperatura") +
    geom_line(colour="red")
)
```

**Gráfica 2**

```
(ggplot(estacionesOriginales[[5]], aes(x = event_time, y = event_value)) +
    ggtitle("Gráfico2") +
    xlab("Hora") +
    ylab("Temperatura") +
    geom_line(colour="green")
)
```

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución pasa por integrar las dos fuentes de datos en una única, con una variable que establezca (imagino yo) cual es la estación. Imaginemos algo así:

```
estacionesNuevas <- list()
estacionesNuevas[[1]] <- data.frame(event_time=1:100, event_value =sample(1:1000,100))
estacionesNuevas[[2]] <- data.frame(event_time=1:100, event_value =sample(100:1500,100))
```

Para integrar las dos bases de datos anteriores en una sola, podemos hacer algo así:

```
new_df <- rbind(
            cbind(estacionesNuevas[[1]], estacion=1),
            cbind(estacionesNuevas[[2]], estacion=2)
)
```

`new_df` es nuestro nueva base de datos, con una nueva columna `estacion`. Ahora graficar esto es muy fácil, solo debemos agregar una nueva dimensión estetica, el color, que se mapeará a la nueva variable `estacion`:

```
ggplot(new_df, aes(x = event_time, y = event_value, color=factor(estacion))) +
    ggtitle("Gráfico1") +
    xlab("Hora") +
    ylab("Temperatura") +
    geom_line()
```

Ejemplo de salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Tengo una pregunta, resulta que los data frames que estoy comparando corresponden a la misma estación (sólo que unos datos son filtrados y los otros brutos), razón por la que no me está graficando dos líneas sino una sola. Debo crear un segundo valor de estación para diferenciar ambas, o hay forma de diferenciarlas sin hacer eso?

Comment: @JorgeRodriguezP, yo use la `estacion` como ejemplo, por que fue lo que me pareció que podía ser. En realidad lo importante es, como juntamos todos los datos, agregar una variable que diferencie cada conjunto, el nombre que le dés es lo de menos, podrá ser `Dataframe_Origen` o mucho mejor, podrías incluso hacer esto: `rbind(cbind(estacionesNuevas[[1]], datos="Brutos"), cbind(estacionesNuevas[[2]], datos="Filtrados"))`, la ventaja de definirlo como una cadena es que luego lo usas tal cual en ggplot sin pasar por un `factor`, es decir `color=datos`.

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias. Procederé a crear dicha variable para diferenciarlos.